# PHP Facebook API: How to retrieve how long I've been friends with someone

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-php-sdk, facebook-friends

I'm curious if it's possible to get the "friendship" information via the Facebook PHP API, meaning information about the friendship the logged in user and one of his friends share?

Information that is visible on this page:

```
https://www.facebook.com/profile.php?id=[YOUR ID]&and=[YOUR FRIENDS' ID]
```

Is this possible?

Comment: What did the facebook API documentation say on the subject?

Comment: Well I've only just started using the PHP SDK so I'm not really familiar with the documentation but upon looking through the pages, it appears it doesn't say anything about it. However, that is true about a lot of functions that the API can do. For instance, the FQL section doesn't list every query you can make.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Via the Graph API you can query the `/me` object.  Two properties you will want `relationship_status` and `significant_other`. I don't see where it specifies the "how long" part.  Not from the Graph API nor from FQL.

Also see `me/family` in the graph.

Comment: Thanks! Not really sure though how you mean query the /me object. How would querying /me give me information about for instance that my brother is listed as a *brother* on Facebook?

Comment: Hi, play with the me/family in the graph https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer

Comment: Okay, I seem to have found a solution to the family part. The "how long" part is still unsolved though. Perhaps it's not even possible with the API..

Comment: I vote for not possible as of yet with the API.  Maybe in the future :)

Comment: Well, it did give me information about if someone is listed as my family, however that wasn't really the original question. I was searching for a way to get information about how long I have been friends with someone. Like, when did I befriend person X(or rather; when did person X get added to my friendslist)? I did play around with the /me object, however nothing came up. Or did you mean that you know that this is possible?

Comment: The answer is: "It is not possible with the current API to know how long"